# How to remove the stain made by pen on leather jacket?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, stain

While writing, I accidentally draw stains on my brown leather jacket. I tried to wash it with water but it did not work and I tried to remove with body spray as well which was a recommendation from friend. It still can be seen on the jacket if there are any other solutions please share.

Comment: What kind of pen/ink were you using at the time?  This makes a huge difference in how you remove the stain.

Comment: I have used ballpoint pen which is blue in color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also use nail polish remover but be careful while using it an use apply it with cotton bug and wipe it off instantly.

Comment: He tried the perfume (he called it body spray) route

Answer (score 0):

Some ball point inks are soluble with alcohol. Try a little bit of rubbing alcohol (70 % isopropanol alcohol) on a cotton ball.

Answer (score 0):

Nail polish remover did not work for me. I had pen marks on my leather jacket at the collar. I used blue tack to stick the collar over the mark so that the mark on my jacket could not be seen when wearing it.

Blu Tack removed the pen stain. It works!